# Twitter Bootstrap Popover add a callback function with event

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to implement a Bootstrap Popover that is positioned based on where the mouse clicked.
It seems that I need both the event to tell me where is the x and y position of the mouse as well as the height and width of the popover to calculate this information correctly.

I am currently doing:

```
var pt = $.fn.popover.Constructor.prototype.show;
  $.fn.popover.Constructor.prototype.show = function () {
    pt.call(this);
    if (this.options.callback) {
      this.options.callback();
    }
  };

$(this).popover({
      container : 'body',
      html: 'true',
      title: '<div id="popover-title">Title </div>',
      content : '<div id="popover-body">Information </div>',
      callback: function() {
        // position calculation here.
      }
    })
```

But I can't figure out how to get event from the callback.

I am also not too sure if this is the correct way of doing this. If not, please point it out.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

I did this to make it work, thanks for the help.

```
$(this).popover({
      placement: 'top',
      container : 'body',
      html: 'true',
      title: '<div id="popover-title">Title </div>',
      content : '<div id="popover-body">Information </div>',
      trigger: 'manual'
    }).click(function (e) {
      var popover = $("#popover-title");
      $(this).popover((popover.length != 0)? 'hide' : 'show');

      popover = $("#popover-title");
      if (popover && popover.parent() && popover.parent().parent()) {
        popover = popover.parent().parent();
      }

      var left = e.pageX;
      var top = e.pageY;
      var height = popover.height();
      var width = popover.width();

      popover.css({
        top: top - height,
        left: left - width / 2 + 'px'
      });
    });
```

Comment: something like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/LAVQt/2/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var flag = false;
    $(document).popover({
        container: 'body',
        html: 'true',
        title: '<div id="popover-title">Title </div>',
        content: '<div id="popover-body">Information </div>',
        trigger: 'manual'
    }).click(function (e) {
        $(this).popover(flag ? 'hide' : 'show');
        flag = !flag;
        var pop = $(this).data('bs.popover');

        //here pop.tip() will give the popover element also e can give the mouse cordinated

        pop.tip().css({
            top: e.pageX,
            legt: e.pageY
        })
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/LAVQt/)

Comment: The demo seems to be a little bit weird, but I took this approach and it seems to help a lot. Thanks. I will update the question soon.

Comment: @user959974 in the demo I just tried to show how to get the mouse position and the popover element.... I didn't try to position the popover correctly.. hopefully you can figure it out